# Check if certain string is on page

Tags: javascript, node.js, acceptance-testing, zombie.js

How can I check if a page contains a certain piece of text with zombie.js? Do I just check the response and see if it has the string?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If you don't use should you can do the following:

```
 assert browser.text('a:contains("Logout")')
```

If you use should.js you can do the following:

```
 browser.response.toString().should.include 'Logout'
```